# golang app with embed static files using reverse proxy

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, gorilla

The code first.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "io/fs"
    "embed"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

//go:embed static/*
var static embed.FS

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
        fSys, err := fs.Sub(static, "static")
    if err != nil {
          panic(err)
    }
    staticServer := http.FileServer(http.FS(fSys))
    router.Handle("/", staticServer)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3001", router); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server could not run")
    }
}
```

So I have this application and two others app2, app3 on ports 3002 and 3003 accordingly.
I need to proxy those apps using apache2 server.

Urls should be http:///app1 http:///app2 http:///app3

If I write:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:3001/
```

so index.html file loads fine but css style not loaded.

html and css files are on the same "virtual" disk. **How can I fix css loading?**

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── static
    ├── index.html
    └── style.css
```

index.html looks like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Error: mesage in browser console:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3001/style.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
```

Comment: hmmm, I think at first <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"> must in the header tag .